# jt class not excute more than one time

Tags: javascript, jquery

i use http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip plugin and jtip class

html code:

```
<a class="jt" href="ajax6.html" rel="ajax6.html" title="jTip Style!">

and jquery :
$('a.jt:eq(0)').cluetip({
  cluetipClass: 'jtip',
  arrows: true,
  dropShadow: false,
  hoverIntent: false,
  sticky: true,
  mouseOutClose: true,
  closePosition: 'title',
  closeText: '<img src="cross.png" alt="close" />'
});
```

but when i want use 2 or more time at class jt just first class working
for example:

```
<a class="jt" href="ajax6.html" rel="ajax6.html" title="jTip Style!">
<a class="jt" href="ajax5.html" rel="ajax5.html" title="jTip Style!">
```

just ajax6 loaded and show tooltip and ajax5 not load tooltip

Comment: [http://api.jquery.com/eq/](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your code is explicitly directing that it only apply to the first `<a>`.

Get rid of that ":eq(0)" in the selector.

```
$('a.jt').cluetip({ ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Pointy is right the eq in your code reduces the set of matched elements to the one at the specified index.
That why you can't catch all elements.